# Cannot add class to div which is created by plugin using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm try to add a class to an existing div which has the id "container" (with `jQuery`). But the added class doesn't appear if I check it in firebug. I have to say that this div is generated by plugin and not by code. And the plugin file is compressed so I can't do any changes.

I tried to add the class to another div. That worked fine. I add it in this way:

```
$('#container').addClass('hdrMenu');
```

Note: The `.addClass` function is inside `$(document).ready()` so this cannot be the problem.

My HTML structure looks like this:

`html > body > section.wrapper.transparent > div.page-box > div#container`

`div#container` and all sub elements were generated by plugin.

Am I doing anything wrong or why can't I add a class to a plugin generated HTML code?

Suggestion appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like a race condition...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen if your code ran before the elements of that plugin were constructed. These elements are not covered by `$(document).ready()`. Also, jQuery would never throw an error if this was the case, and you'll have no idea what happened.

Place your code to run *after* these elements are constructed.

Comment: Ah that's because the console was empty. Don't know why I didn't thought about that. Thank you very much! You made my day :) I will accept the answer as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

That might be because this code that you're having is executed when there is no div with the id container. So the class name is not applied and then the content is loaded into the DOM. Here might be the example of such

```
<script>
   /* jquery code */
   $('#container').addClass('hdrMenu');
</script>
```

And then after all this code, you're executing the code to create the elements as

```
$('#container').load('data.html');
```

So, always remember: Place the jQuery script file at the top of the script files

```
<head>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  /* other script files */
</head>
```